# gitlab workflow rules and if

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am reading this snippet from the [gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflow)

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /-draft$/
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

I thought that when we have `rules` only one `if` has to be `true` for the rule to be considered `true` as a whole. But the explanation for the snippet says:

> In this example, pipelines run if the commit title (first line of the
> commit message) does not end with -draft and the pipeline is for
> either:
>
> - A merge request
> - The default branch.

Where does that `either` come from? Shouldn't only one hold true?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the confusion. `either` here has the same meaning as a logical inclusive "or". That is: _if the pipeline is for a merge request or the default branch_. Which seems to match your understanding that only (at least) one of these must be true.

Comment: @sytech: you don't take into account the first if. I.e. if the commit title ends in `-draft` do not run. If that is `true` isn't that enough?

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline will run if:

- title NOT match the string

AND

- it's a merge request event

OR

- it's the default branch

Answer (score 0):

I suppose some brackets would help here... That **NOT** makes all the difference.

(title **NOT** match the string) **AND** ((it's a merge request event) **OR** (it's the default branch))

I suppose the best way to view it is to include the default when:always in the code... This does not need to be added, since it's the default, but I think it helps.

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /-draft$/
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: always
```